# nservicebus host won't remove messages from the queue

Tags: email, smtp, queue, nservicebus, msmq

So I got my host handling messages. what it does? getting the message that contains email address, body and subject. and send the email using smtp.

so in production, in one of our clients, I see 370 messages in the queue. no messages are getting out of the queue. only new messages are getting in.

I looked at the log. what is see is this:

```
2016-04-28 17:35:10,243 [DAPROD01] [3] [] INFO : Failed to process message
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at  EmailServiceHost.Utilities.EmailSender.Send(String recipient, String subject, String body) in e:\r-release\src\EmailServiceHost\Utilities\EmailSender.cs:line 24
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.HandlerInvocationCache.Invoke(Object handler, Object message, Dictionary`2 dictionary) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.InvokeHandlersBehavior.DispatchMessageToHandlersBasedOnType(IBuilder builder, LogicalMessage toHandle, LoadedMessageHandlers loadedHandlers, BehaviorContext context) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.InvokeHandlersBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Sagas.SagaPersistenceBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.CallbackInvocationBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.ApplyIncomingMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline.Behaviors.ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
   at NServiceBus.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(BehaviorContext context, Action next) in :line 0
2016-04-28 17:35:10,602 [DAPROD01] [48] [] ERROR: Message has failed FLR and will be moved to the configured error q, ID=ec40ebe5-90a5-4014-be42-a5f500877d2a.
2016-04-28 17:36:50,689 [DAPROD01] [48] [] INFO : Failed to process message
System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
   at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in :line 0
```

so you notice that the first error contains the timeout of the smtp client.
the next 200 errors only say Failed to process message.

the messages are not getting out of the private queue.

Comment: Are the messages being moved to the error queue or are they staying on the input queue?

Comment: I'm with Tom. If messages keep failing, they should be moved to the error queue bij NServiceBus. It's possible they're picked up and moved into the queue again, or moved into the retries queue or the error queue. What are your settings on first level retries, second level retries and error and audit queues?

Comment: They are not getting into the error queue. I got all the default settings (meaning 5 FLR and no SLR). the messages are just staying in the queue.

Comment: So I wrote this small utility to pull messages from the queue and it worked. now the question is - why nservice bus host (it is a windows service) stop working and not pulling messages from the queue? any ideas? we got nothing in the log and in the event viewer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A messagehandler processes messages in a Transaction.  When it receives an exception while handling a message, the transaction is rolled back and the message is put back on the queue.

It looks like your messagehandler is not able to send a mail.  Either the smtp server is down, unavailable or a firewall prohibits the connection to it.  The timeout exception you get causes the transaction to rollback.

Eventually NServiceBus should move a message that keeps failing to the error queue.  I don't know what that doesn't happen here.  Maybe you are just not waiting long enough?  BTW, I think the default settings are 5 FLRs and 3 SLRs.